# Arrays.copyOfRange generic array creation mechanism

Tags: java, arrays, generics

In the following static utility method of the `Arrays` class `public static <T> T[] copyOfRange(T[] original, int from, int to)`. How does it create an array of type `T[]` since in java we can not create generic arrays as it will result in a **generic array creation** error. Does it just create an array of type `Object[]`, do an unchecked cast to `T[]` and then return the result ?

Comment: did you try reading the source?

Comment: Just check the source code of the JDK, it is available e.g. here: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/Arrays.java?av=f

Comment: *Does it just create an array of type Object[], do an unchecked cast to T[] and then return the result* -> yes

Comment: to create the array, it's ultimately using private static native method `Array.newArray`, which takes a componentType, then eventually an unchecked cast to `T[]`. So to be fair you can't read the source of that native method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an array of a component type determined at runtime by using the method [`java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance-java.lang.Class-int-)

`copyOfRange` can get the component type at runtime by getting it out of the array object passed in, by doing something like `original.getClass().getComponentType()`. (`.getClass()` gets the `Class` object representing the actual array type, and the calling `.getComponentType` on that `Class` object representing the array type gets the `Class` object representing its component type.)